# Is it possible to style the shadow root container itself?

Tags: html, css

Wondering if it's possible to style the shadow root container? I have these attached to a parent custom element, and would like the custom element to always carry a `margin: 5px`.

Instead of adding this to the document's CSS, I would like to encapsulate this into the template attached to the component. But shadow root isn't quite an HTMLElement, so is the only way to add a `<div>` inside the template that acts as the container, and style that `<div>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is probably using the `:host` CSS selector. Using `:root` inside the shadow DOM does not get to a `document` as there is none inside the shadow DOM, and the selector is not allowed to ascend out of the shadow DOM encapsulation.

Hint: if your `host` doesn't have `display: inline-block` it may not apply `background` or `border` as you expected.